# VueJs doesnot update ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Hi I have created a chat box and wants to scroll to bottom when loaded and when new message is sent.

For some reason following is not working

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" id="messages" ref="scrollList">
</div>

mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(this.$refs.scrollList.scrollTop = this.$refs.scrollList.scrollHeight)
},
```

I have tried using following as well, added a `div` with id of `bottom` at the bottom of `messages` div.

```
<div id="bottom"></div>

mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView(false))
},
```

This did not work as well.

When I print the data in console, I can see that scrollTop = 0 and scrollHeight = 515 but not updating the scroll.

Thank you

Comment: this is because the content wasn't render when the scrolltop is set in mounted.

Comment: doesnt work when I add new message to the array. Page stays at the same position

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/directives/scroll/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

One of these should work:

```js
// 1
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.$refs.scrollList.scrollTop = this.$refs.scrollList.scrollHeight
        }, 100)
    })
    
}

// 2
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.$refs.scrollList.scrollTop = 99999
        }, 100)
    })
    
}
```

## EDIT

Not even sure if `setTimeout()` is useful. I think the main problem is that `.nextTick()` expects a function as an argument and you are not giving a function:

from : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

```js
// modify data
vm.msg = 'Hello'
// DOM not updated yet
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
})
```

Comment: can you please explain why setTimeOut?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this helps. If the error is because the height is not available yet, waiting some more milliseconds might work.

Did you try with and without ?

Comment: Height is available though, because when I `console.log` both `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` it has different values 0 and 550 or more respectively.

Comment: values of `scrollHeight` is  not assigned to `scrollTop`. `ScrollTop` is 0 even after doing `scrollTop = scrollHeight`.