# Vue nexttick not working for scrollTop inside watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a rather simple question but can't seem to figure it out.

I have a watcher which watches for the route, and when it detects that route, i basically want to navigate to the last scrolled position of the user.

```
$route(to, from) {
      let currentPath = to.path;
      if (currentPath === "/") {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.board.scrollTop = this.lastScrollPosition; // fails
        });
      }
    },
```

This doesn't seem to work for me although I came across a few posts that recommend it. ([VueJs doesnot update ScrollTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337683/vuejs-doesnot-update-scrolltop), [Vue method scroll div to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658042/vue-method-scroll-div-to-top))

However, setting a timeout of >= 100ms seems to work.

```
$route(to, from) {
      let currentPath = to.path;
      if (currentPath === "/") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$refs.board.scrollTop = this.lastScrollPosition; // works
        }, 100);
      }
    },
  },
```

I'm hoping to find a way in which `this.$nextTick` should work. Thanks in advance for the guidance!

Comment: You should try with the built-in feature - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Comment: Oh! i didnt know that existed, will check it out :)

Comment: one of the issues im facing with the built-in feature is that it looks like it handles page scroll, I'm looking for preserving a component scroll as well...